# Why is my ISO setting changing in manual mode?

Tags: nikon, iso, manual-mode, auto-iso

I want to use Manual Mode but I don't understand why, when I set my ISO to 100, I see in the picture settings that the ISO changed to 3200.  How can I set it up to be what I set and not what the camera set? I was watching some videos but I don't have auto ISO on my D3100. Do I need to change to other settings?

Answer (score 5):

You appear to have a Nikon camera. On all other brands, one chooses from a list of ISO sensitivities or *Auto*. The camera then uses the specified ISO for every option other than *Auto*.

With Nikon, if you have *Automatic Sensitivity Control* enabled in the *Shooting* menu, then the camera will use selected ISO as the *default* and actually select another sensitivity, up to the a user-specified maximum.

To change this behavior, simply set *Automatic Sensitivity Control* to *Off*.

Comment: This exact problem happened to me. Thank you for your answer.